# Populating E-commerce Tables with Products and Variants

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, dataframe

I'm in the process of building a fashion aggregation website, and have come across a products and variants problem.

To describe the data - one product can have many variants. e.g, 'Summer Dress' that comes in 3 colours and 8 sizes.  As such this product would have 24 variant products, the generic being the 'parent' product. Each variant may have different pricing, availability, sizing, colour etc.

My question concerns table population - my scrapers output every variant of every product with their associated data, which can be in CSV or pandas DataFrame format. Can any of you tell me how I would go about populating two database tables from this data:

1. Table with the parent product, with foreign keys to each of its variants
2. All variant products of a parent product, linked to that product such that on my eventual website, they can all be found through searching the foreign keys of the parent product.

I've already tried to create a single table, 'products', and assigned each product variant the same UUID, but the searches were painfully slow. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks considerable detail so by necessity any answer must also lack detail. But the following is a possible solution. The process is to first load a staging table (perhaps this is current 'products' table can serve that function). This table is transient as its content is basically valid for a single load, but it persists between sessions. Something like:

```
create table product_variants_stage( product_name text  
                                    , var_class    text 
                                    , var_val      text  
                                     -- ...   other product/variant attributes
                                    ); 

create table products( prod_id  uuid  default gen_random_uuid() primary key
                      , name    text not null unique
                      --... other product attributes
                      ) ; 
                     
create table variants ( prod_var_id  uuid  default gen_random_uuid()  primary key 
                       , prod_id     uuid  not null 
                                     references products(prod_id) 
                       , var_class   text not null
                       , var_val     text not null
                       -- ... other variant attributes for each variant
                       , constraint prod_var_bk unique (prod_id, var_class, var_val)         
                       ) ;
```

Now create a procedure which will populate both the Product and Variant tables unique Business Keys (product name, variant class, and variant value).

```
create or replace procedure load_product_variants()
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    insert into products ( name
                           --...
                          ) 
      select product_name
              --... 
        from product_variants_stage
       where  product_name is not null
      on conflict (name) do nothing; 
     
   insert into variants ( prod_id
                         , var_class
                         , var_val 
                         --... 
                         )
         select p.prod_id
              , s.var_class
              , s.var_val 
               --... 
           from product_variants_stage s
           join products               p 
             on s.product_name = p.name
          where s.var_class is not null  
            and s.var_val is not null  
     on conflict (prod_id,var_class,var_val) do nothing;       

    commit; 
end;
$$;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aa66481abea92200cb3907e2b6804387).  
Note: Demo built with Postgres 13. If you are not on that version you will need another function for generating the uuids. You also may need to define the procedure load_product_variants as a function that returns void (and remove the commit).